# 413 Request Entity Too Large -Gravitee

Tags: request, entity, http-status-code-413, gravitee

Registered a Java Rest api with gravitee. This api is for uploading the images to a minio bucket. I am getting the error:
413 Request Entity Too Large

I have already tried:

1. Add "Request Content Limit" policy. This is not helping
2. In general settings - Allow upload images and specified the size